# 2 similar LINQ statements with different syntax yielding different output

Tags: linq

I have to modify some old code in an application that someone before me made.  Looking at the variable below whose result goes into "test", I have two tables (which are set up with relational models).  In the variable "test2", I have rewritten the query in the more SQL syntax (which I'm used to).  I want to join on the Lines and Shifts table where the LineId's match.  When I view the "test2" output, I get 6 values where the end time is 2-28-2017 8:30, 9:30 ... 1:30, and 2:30.  That makes sense.  When I view the "test" output, I see one Line with around 500 Shift entries associated to it.  Inspecting those elements yields end times that go back to 2017.  Should I not get the same 6 entries in the "test" output that I got back in the "test2" output?  Is there something that I'm missing behind the scenes that linq is doing different in the "test" output? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var test = entityFrameworkDateModel.Lines.Where(line => line.Shifts.Any(s => shift.EndTime >= DateTime.Now));
var test2 = from line in entityFrameworkDateModel.Lines
            join shift in entityFrameworkDateModel.Shifts on line.LineID equals shift.LineId
            where shift.EndTime >= DateTime.Now
            select new
            {
                line.LineID,
                shift.EndTime
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test is a collection of Line objects that has 0 to many Shift objects. I would expect that

```
test.SelectMany(t => t.Shifts).Count() == 500 // approx. 500 anyways
```

test2 is a collection of AnonymousObjects. test2 is flattening your data with one object per LineId / Shift End Time pair. Where as test is keeping your data in a hierarchy.

> Inspecting those elements yields end times that go back to 2017.

Test can and will contain shifts that are not matching your where criteria. Since you are only returning Line objects that have shifts with an end time greater than now. So your Line object will have 1 or more shifts matching `EndTime >= DateTime.Now`. But the `.Any()` does not filter out the other Shift objects Where `EndTime < DateTime.Now.`

---

You can add a SelectMany then Where to return all Shift objects matching your criteria:

```
var test = entityFrameworkDateModel.Lines
    .SelectMany(line => line.Shifts)
    .Where(shift => shift.EndTime >= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.  However, I can't replace the .Any() with a .Where()  to filter out the Shift objects.  I can do the .Where() clause on my results from "test" in a second query statement by doing:     var filterValues = test.SelectMany(t => t.Shifts.Where(nestedT => nestedT.EndTime >= DateTime.Now));  Is there a syntactical way to combine the second where clause into the original query?  (I feel as if there is but this linq syntax is harder for me to generate, whereas the more SQL syntax of linq is easier to generate.)

Comment: Thanks that is crystal clear.  Select all of your Shifts from you Lines join and then filter your times of the Shifts that you have from the SelectMany clause.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 are not the same, even though they feel similar. For the first query, the nested "any" filtering isn't needed. The "where" alone is enough. The any is actually going to return just true, which will short circuit the where. I'd lay out the correct syntax for the where clause, but I'm on mobile SO and can't see the question while I'm answering